# How can i create a module that will create a type writer effect? (PYTHON)

Tags: python, module

```
      from time import sleep
import sys

for line in lines:         
    for c in line:
        print(c, end='')          
        sys.stdout.flush()  
        sleep(0.05)        
print('')
```

How can i convert this into a module so that all the text within my code has a similar affect?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean convert it into a function so that you can use the same code over and over again, but with different text each time? If so, you can do something like this (slightly modified from yours, but not much):

```
from time import sleep
import sys

def SlowWrite(text):

    for line in text:     
        for c in line:
            print(c, end='')
            sys.stdout.flush()
            sleep(0.05)
    print()

SlowWrite("Hello, everyone! Look at me and my fancy typewriter.");
SlowWrite(["I love this thing so much...", "It's my new favourite toy"]);
```

If you wanted to extend it, you could add a second input, `delay`, and use that in your sleep function. Then you could also choose how slow it types every time you use it...